How to make shared pointer from raw pointer and make other shared pointers aware of it?
I have some hierarchy (through composition, not inheritance) of classes: Child and Parent. Child can have multiple parents, also Parent could do the same. I want the Child class lifetime being managed by Parent classes.
Class structure:
class Parent
{
public:
std::shared_ptr<Child> my_chld;
};

class Child
{
...some stuff...
public:
void setParent(Parent* parent)
{
parent->my_child=this;
}
};

And main() looks like this:
Parent* prnt1=new Parent();
Parent* prnt2=new Parent();
Child* chld=new Child();
chld->setParent(prnt1);
chld->setParent(prnt2);
delete prnt1;

And I want the chld to stay alive until all parents will deleted (so they are managing child lifetime), how to do that? In my version my_chld pointer not aware about another pointer managing same object, so that is a problem. Or is this approach completely wrong?
EDIT:
To explain context. I prefer to stay with raw pointers in main because I am writing my own GUI library, something like Qt, and currently implementing animation system, where same animation(the Child) can be used in multiple places(multiple animation groups(the Parent) or other objects). And like in other frameworks user creates mostly everything on heap with new in place where needs. And just like in Qt/GTK it is ok to pointers became invalidated after parent destruction because ownership of objects taken by Parent.

"it is ok to pointers became dangling because ownership of objects taken by some kind of Parent" -- I'm pretty sure "dangling" is not the right word to convey what you mean. A dangling pointer would occur if ownership was not taken. A dangling pointer is one that (is alive and) pointed to an object that is no longer alive.You seem to mean the opposite: the pointer is no longer alive, but the object is still alive (which is fine if something else has ownership, and a memory leak otherwise, but not "dangling" in either case).

"To explain context. I prefer to stay with raw pointers in main because I am writing my own GUI library" -- I don't see how that explains staying with raw pointers. In fact, the rest of your explanation looks like a reason for not using raw pointers (so that ownership of an object is not in question).

@JaMiT nearly all C++ frameworks by default use raw pointers to create inctances of GUI objects, not the shared, that is tradition and maybe have some reasons too.

"maybe have some reasons too" -- Blindly following "everyone else is doing it" can lead you into a pitfall. You should understand those reasons before deciding to rule out other possibilities. (For example, if I recall correctly, gtkmm allows raw pointers because the parents don't necessarily own their children. And the children don't necessarily live on the heap. That's a much different scenario than your design.) As I said, your explanation fails to explain why raw pointers are desirable.

If you need to use new, or users of your framework need to use new, you're doing modern C++ wrong.

std::shared_ptr does not work out of the box with this. The first thing to make it work is to inherit from std::enable_shared_from_this. Like this
class Child : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Child>
{
    ...
};

When you have done this you use the shared_from_this method to create shared_ptrs from this
void Child::setParent(Parent* parent)
{
    parent->my_child = shared_from_this();
}

Also raw pointers don't mix well with shared_ptr or enable_shared_from_this, so you should also change your main to create shared pointers (at least of the children, but probably the parents too).
int main()
{
    ...
    auto chld = std::make_shared<Child>();
    chld->setParent(prnt1);
    chld->setParent(prnt2);


And if I stay with raw pointers in main, will chld properly deleted after deleting all parents? I have some reasons to stay with raw pointers in main.

@SupremeMachine "if I stay with raw pointers in main" - don't do that. You should not be using raw pointers at all when ownership is an issue.  In your example, prnt1 and prnt2 are owning pointers and should be unique_ptrs, and chld is an owning pointer and should be a shared_ptr. Using a raw pointer in setParent() is fine since it is just a viewing pointer not an owning pointer, you can then pass in prnt1.get() and prnt2.get() as the raw pointer

Interesting that the standard basically has a solution tailored to the OP's problem. Apparently, others have had similar problems.

@SupremeMachine expand on those reasons in the question body. Reason: The vast majority of the time when people decide to mix-n-match raw and smart pointers, they're only doing it to shoot themselves in the foot somewhere else in the program and simply haven't found that future problem yet. Your case may be one of those rare exceptions where what's normally a really bad idea is actually the right thing to do, but if you explain why you want to do this, we can either show you how to get what you want or guide you down a path that'll work better.

@SupremeMachine Yes, if you delete the parent pointers in main then all the child pointers will also be deleted.

Simple way would be to change interface:
class Child
{
};

class Parent
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Child> my_child;
};


void setChild(Parent& parent, std::shared_ptr<Child> child)
{
    parent.my_child = std::move(child);
}

int main()
{
    Parent prnt1;
    Parent prnt2;
    auto chld = std::make_shared<Child>();
    setChild(prnt1, chld);
    setChild(prnt2, chld);
}

Demo
Else, you might use std::enable_shared_from_this.
but shared_from_this should only be called from pointer own by std::shared_ptr. You might enforce that with "factory":
class Child;

class Parent
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Child> my_child;
};

class Child : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Child>
{
    class Key{
        friend Child;

        Key() {}
    };
public:
    explicit Child(Key) {}
    Child(const Child&) = delete;

    static std::shared_ptr<Child> create() { return std::make_shared<Child>(Key{}); }

    void setParent(Parent& parent) {
        parent.my_child = shared_from_this();
    }
};


int main()
{
    Parent prnt1;
    Parent prnt2;
    auto child = Child::create();
    child->setParent(prnt1);
    child->setParent(prnt2);
}

Demo

You're mixing raw pointers and shared pointers which causes problems. To keep your Child alive until all Parents are deleted you gotta use shared pointers everywhere.
Create your Parent and Child with std::make_shared, so they are shared pointers.
When you assign the Child to a Parent, copy the shared pointer.
This way, the Child's reference count increases.
It won't be deleted until all Parents are gone.
Avoid raw pointers, they don't manage ownership.

Challenge
Let me start by challenging the question.

I prefer to stay with raw pointers in main because I am writing my own GUI library, something like Qt, [...] And like in other frameworks user creates mostly everything on heap with new in place where needs. And just like in Qt/GTK it is ok to pointers became invalidated after parent destruction because ownership of objects taken by Parent.

This is bogus reasoning. You have stated a preference because that is how you perceive it's always been done. There is value in learning from and leveraging what has been done in the past. However, blindly following the past is ill-advised. Blindly following an ill-perceived past is even worse.
You mentioned GTK, which is a C library, yet you are writing in C++. That alone can lead to bad practices. It would be better to use the C++ binding, gtkmm, as a model. And if you do that, your argument collapses, given this quote from the gtkmm documentation (emphasis added):

gtkmm allows the programmer to control the lifetime (that is, the construction and destruction) of any widget in the same manner as any other C++ object. This flexibility allows you to use new and delete to create and destroy objects dynamically or to use regular class members (that are destroyed automatically when the class is destroyed) or to use local instances (that are destroyed when the instance goes out of scope).

In gtkmm, widgets can be local instances instead of being on the heap. Admittedly, the underlying GTK object is dynamically allocated, but that is not the user's perspective. I also admit that it might make sense for you to require that your widgets be dynamically allocated. I am not questioning your decision to require dynamic allocation; I am challenging your assertion that that is the only way GUI libraries operate.
To be fair, the next part of the quote does support your assertion in some, but not all, cases.

This flexibility is not present in some C++ GUI toolkits, which restrict the programmer to only a subset of C++'s memory management features.

My point is that your decision to require dynamic allocation is valid, and at the same time it is not an excuse to use raw pointers. Seize the opportunity to be better than others. Expose your use of smart pointers and force the people using your library to follow good memory management.
Fragility
It's worth noting that your decision to not use smart pointers makes use of your library more subject to bugs. For example, the following function would compile with your interface, demonstrating that your approach fails to require dynamic allocation of widgets.
void foo(Parent& prnt1) {
    Child chld;
    chld.setParent(&prnt1);
}

Raw pointers are insufficient to force dynamic allocation of objects. Use them when there is no alternative (e.g. in C). When smart pointers are available, use them.
Solution
It looks to me like your design is awkward because you tell the child to attach to a parent. (Well, you call it "set" the parent, but that terminology is imprecise when a child can have multiple parents.) If you swap the roles of parent and child when calling your function, you can have an interface that is just as easy to use and that avoids the question of how to get a shared_ptr from this. That is, move (and rename) your method from the Child class to the Parent class.
Also, go ahead and force the parameter to be a smart pointer. There is no need to hide the fact that you're using a shared pointer from your users, and it will make their code look better if they can avoid using new.
class Child
{
    // Some stuff
};

class Parent
{
    std::shared_ptr<Child> my_child;
  public:
    void attachChild(std::shared_ptr<Child> child) {
        my_child = std::move(child);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Parent prnt1;
    Parent prnt2;
    auto chld = std::make_shared<Child>();
    prnt1.attachChild(chld);
    prnt2.attachChild(chld);
}

While this snippet does not force the parents to be dynamically allocated, it causes no problem for attaching a child. Presumably, there will be other parts of your API that will do to parents what this change did to children (i.e. force them to be managed by shared_ptr).

It is true that std::enable_shared_from_this would allow you to stick to your original design, but to me, that looks like extra work on your part, possibly extra work on your user's part, and no gain.
